# How can I scroll the results of a multisearch query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tried the following two ways to scroll the results of an elasticsearch multisearch query.

**Approach #1**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_msearch?scroll=10m" -d'
{ "type": "parent" }
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
{ "type": "child" }
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
'
```

**Approach #2**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_msearch" -d'
{ "type": "parent", "scroll": "10m" }
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
{ "type": "child", "scroll": "10m" }
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
'
```

Both approaches don't seem to work, since they don't return a scroll ID in the response. What can I do? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to get it done? 
- scroll in multisearch ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `from` and `size` - these can be used alongside each query. eg:

```
{ "type": "parent" }
{ "from":20,"size":10, "query": {...}}
```

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-from-size.html